# Κeyboard shortcut to switch to a specific input source

Tags: macos, keyboard, language, input-source

For a multilingual user, with 3 or 4 everyday-use languages, is it possible to press a keyboard shortcut to change to a pre-set language?

For example, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> will be English, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> will be German, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> will be Russian.

For my needs, the specific shortcut or specific language is not relevant, but just want to avoid the frustrating sequential press of the regular language switch keyboard shortcut in order to achieve the needed input source.

Also, if it's possible to find some solution that is not a keyboard shortcut, but for example a trackpad gesture - it will be fine.

Comment: It's not going to be possible by the usual method of applying a key command to a menu item, as there's no 'front-most' app it's a menu of. It might be possible by Applescript, but that's not my strong suit, sorry.

Comment: In case on 4 languages best case scenario is two keystrokes and worse case scenario is four using built-in shortcut. If I compare it to switch from one language to another and touch typing layout change then it’s piece of cake. You mentioned Russian layout which have very little similarity with English. If you have problem with two keystrokes and no problem of switching between languages and layouts I sincerely envy you.

Comment: @AivarPaalberg I have no problem with 4, but I mentioned this number for the sake of simplicity, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use [Kawa](https://github.com/hatashiro/kawa) for this.

Comment: No built-in solution without scripting?

Comment: @Cocktail  Not as far as I know.  For your specific example, I would use US International PC or US for both English and German (the accented characters are easily made) and switch back and forth to Russian via Caps Lock.